# How to link with a .la library file on linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries

I am using an open source library and it builds to a file like libshared.la. Can i statically link with this file using normal gcc commands?  I'm more familiar with the dynamic linking of .so file and the static linking of .a files.  Not sure about .la though. 
thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is a libtool file. You can use it using `libtool`:

```
$ libtool --mode=link gcc -g -O -o test test.o \
                     /usr/local/lib/libhello.la
```

More about `libtool`:

- http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Using-libtool.html